# In install4j with a multi-platform project, how do I change the -Xmx setting based on platform?

Tags: install4j

We're bundling a 64 bit JRE on OS X, because that's all there is for OS X.

We're bundling a 32 bit JRE on Windows, to ensure people can install our software if they are using 32-bit Windows.

The max heap size we'd like to set is therefore considerably different based on platform. For OS X, the default is good. On Windows, we'd like to set it to  -Xmx512m.

I think the correct place to set the -Xmx setting in install4j is **Launchers** -> **Java Invocation** -> **VM Parameters**. But I don't know how to add this to the VM Parameters text field **if and only if** OS == Windows. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a compiler variable.

On the "General Settings->Compiler Variables" step, add a variable named "xmxParam" and an empty value.

In the launcher wizard, add

```
${compiler:xmxParam}
```

to the VM parameters text field.

You can then override the default value for each media file. In the media wizard of the Windows media file, go to the "Customize project defaults->Compiler variables" step and override "xmxParam" with "-Xmx512m".

Comment: Thanks Ingo, that seems to achieve what I'm after.